# Kernels and the Sign Function

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to define the kernel of the sign function ($sgn:S_n \to \left\{-1,+1\right\}$) for $S_4$.

Is the identity element of the range of the sign function +1?

Kind of confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, {$-1,1$} is a (two-element) multiplicative group with identity element $1$,

so anything that gets mapped to $1$ is in the kernel.